# Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/image/ (String)

Tags: flutter, yaml

I am getting the following exception in my pubspec.yaml file :

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/image/ (String).
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at D:\Working_Project\FlutterProject\flutter_change_color\pubspec.yaml
```

Comment: Please share your pubspec.yaml file here.

Comment: suggest you give some more context

Comment: Add a space after "-" - assets/image/image.jpg

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error I figured out that you must add assets like  following:

Flutter uses the 'pubspec.yaml' file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app.
Here is an example:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
```

Now lets come to your Error

**Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/image/ (String).**

This Error has occurred as you did not add space between "- and assets". If you just add space It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 11):

Using the correct format in pubspec.yaml file is very important.
use:

```
assets:
   - assets/images
```

(space between the strings `-` and `assets/images` is necessary)

Answer (score 9):

You need to put a space between dash(-) and the "assets"

```
- assets/image/
```

Comment: This solved my problem. The space does matter.

Answer (score 1):

uses-material-design: true

# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - images/pic.jpeg
  - images/pic1.jpeg

aligned uses-material-design: true and assets: to the margin 
then flutter clean 
then flutter run

Answer (score 1):

write your list of assets inside the square brackets

```
  assets: [-assets/example.png]
```

Answer (score 1):

flutter returns this error because the input is not correctly formatted.

the correct format is as follows

```
flutter:
 assets:
  -folder/file.png
```

Comment: u need a space after the_

Answer (score 0):

in PUBSPEC.YAML
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:

INSTEAD OF
   { -assets/image/image name}

USE

{- assets/image/image name}

Answer (score 0):

- just create a assets folder with the name images(put your images in there)
- open your pubspec.yaml file
- copy and paste  or adjust the file by removing # to
  assets:

  - images/

to your pub spec.yaml under flutter uses-material-design: true

run flutter pub get afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

add a space between Hypen(-)  and the directory name as suggested in comments.

```dart
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - images/card1[][1].jpg
```

[working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4rbH.png)

Answer (score -1):

if the problem persists and you seem to have written correctly as indicated above, I think you have to restart the application you are using. visual studio code mostly has that problem

Comment: A bit of an overkill, is'nt it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).